# Weird XAML problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I am creating a XAML based application and running into a funky problem that isn't making any sense to me at all.

The problem: I make changes on my XAML, very minor ones such as changing the text content on my buttons. The design field reflects these changes as they should. However, when I run the project, the changes do not render themselves. The same window renders itself but the text content that was altered in the buttons do not change itself.

The problem is a microcosm of the bigger problem, which is that any kind of back end changes I make such as the data binding do not reflect themselves when the app is executed.

I am still exploring where i could be going wrong, but if anyone has any leads on this, I will much appreciate it!!!!

Thanks,

Parijat Kalia

Comment: Have you looked at the `Output` window whilst debugging?

Answer (score 1):

Delete your pdb files from bin/debug and rebuild your application.

Comment: If your still having issues, you can delete the hidden obj folders in your project. This has done the trick for me sometimes too.

Comment: @Parijat Kalia. Pdb (Program Database) files hold debugging and project state information. This includes source file names and their lines and the local variable names. Sometimes the code is modified but the pdb files are not updated. Hence due to this difference you would see issues like "no symbols are loaded" and sometimes the changes won't reflect. In those cases it is best to manually delete these pdb files and perform a rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, Visual Studio (the compiler, more accurately) sometimes does not detect small changes made to the code. Doing a Clean or a Rebuild (which, IIRC, is a Clean & Build) should force VS to recompile all files without needing to check for changes.

The logic behing the changes detection is to speed up compilation, compiling only the changed files.